# When detecting a brand logo Using 'Yolov7' how to label better results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

While using 'yolov7'

When labeling to detect the brand logo, is it good to label the letter logo in a large box format? Or is it better to label delicately according to the shape of the letters?

Logo data is learned by labeling in two cases.

One is to label the logo with text and images in a large box format.

The rest is to label the shape of the logo image and letters in as much detail as possible.

At this point, most logos are recognized fine, but some are not.

To further improve performance, I want to know if labeling is good in one way, and if I have to do only one thing, which of the ways I do is good.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic]. this does not appear to be a coding question. try a different stack exchange site?